# How to autorun Python files every 5 hours (use Redis Queue)

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

I have a code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def loaddata():

    # Execute link
    url = "https://genvita.vn/thu-thach/7-ngay-detox-da-dep-dang-thon-nguoi- 
          khoe-qua-soc-len-den-8-trieu-dong"
    driver_path = ()
    global browser
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
    browser.get(url)

    read_mores = browser.find_elements_by_link_text('XEM THÊM')
    while len(read_mores) >= 1:
        for read_more in read_mores:
            browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", read_more)
            browser.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", read_more)
        read_mores = browser.find_elements_by_link_text('XEM THÊM')

    read_mores2 = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='load- 
                  more-replies']")

    for read_mores2 in read_mores2:
        morecomment = read_mores2.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
        browser.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", morecomment)
```

I auto scroll down and auto click button website with text :'XEM THÊM'.

I want to auto run this file every 5 hours my file will run, when i shutdown my computer, it will be stop.

Can I do that with *Redis Queue* ? I don't wannt to do with : Schedule Task or Crontab.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do that with Redis Queue?

No. To consume tasks from redis, your script must be always running (in which case you might as well simply sleep for 5 hours, without redis). Plus, something must *put* tasks into redis.

Comment: sorry, can you explain again. 
I search google and I saw a post : https://timber.io/blog/background-tasks-in-python-using-task-queues/. 
I cann't set time to autorun my Python file, right?

Comment: @ToanNguyenPhuoc: that post talks about "workers". A worker has to be running, or else it has no way of getting new tasks from redis.

Comment: "I cann't set time to autorun my Python file, right?"  - that is precisely what crontab is for.

Comment: and, do you know how many way to do this ( except Schedules Task and Crontab)